# Novel with nanotech, a utopia isolated from grey goo, and an AI in the protagonist's head

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia, nanotechnology

The only reason I even remembered the plot was due to the nanite use. I don't think the plot is very original and is similar to at least a dozen other books written in the last 10 years, but I figured I'd post and see of anyone else has read it. What I remember about the plot:

1. 18ish year old lives in a seeming utopia that has a barrier around the under 18/not adult section that separates it from other areas.
2. Nanites are inside people's bodies allowing them to make food from thin air.
3. There is an AI in his head, although that's revealed later on. Can appear to the main character in some kind of altered mind state. Wants the main character to help her end the "simulation" that is tying up her system resources.
4. Some kind of virtual reality is used to give the main character "tests" that change him somehow? Accompanied by the perception of time slowing.
5. I distinctly remember a tractor being involved somewhere.
6. One of the tests had a tower the main character had to climb to "win".
7. I dont think this is a YA, as I remember reading a lot of swearing.
8. The main character hurts his leg in a forest type area escaping with a girl he saved.
9. The main character is eventually caught and an old, maybe 200 years old, white-haired doctor tries to euthanize him. Doctor complains about remembering the past and comments on how they wipe the communities memories to keep them safe or something.
10. Severe ban on certain entertainment. Pulp fiction was mentioned specifically.
11. Behind a barrier, there is some kind of grey goo nanotech supposedly trying to kill the world.
12. It was an ongoing series last I read it, 3 or so years ago (around 2014-2015). I only read book one and I believe this is some kind of indie book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer while browsing Amazon. It's Dima Zales's *The Last Humans* series, which starts with *[Oasis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27830478-oasis)*.

[image: Oasis - Book 1 of The Last Humans]

> My name is Theo, and I'm a resident of Oasis, the last habitable area on Earth. It's meant to be a paradise, a place where we are all content. Vulgarity, violence, insanity, and other ills are but a distant memory, and even death no longer plagues us.
>
> I was once content too, but now I'm different. Now I hear a voice in my head, and she tells me things no imaginary friend should know. Her name is Phoe, and she is my delusion.
>
> Or is she?

Comment: We generally ask people to elaborate on their answers, explaining why they match up. I've added a link and a blurb to your answer, but if you can point out other matching points, that would help.